# Integral of $\frac{1}{t^{2}-1}$

Tags: analysis, indefinite-integrals

When I solve the indefinite integral $\int \frac{1}{t^{2}-1}$  with partial fraction decomposition I obtain 
$$\int \frac{1}{t^{2}-1} dt=\int \frac{1}{2(t-1)} - \frac{1}{2(t+1)} dt=\frac{1}{2}(\ln(t-1)-\ln(t+1))+C$$

But when I compare it with Wolfram Alpha, they have 
$$\frac{1}{2}(\ln(1-t)-\ln(t+1))+C$$

$\ln(t-1) \neq \ln(1-t)$ , did I calculate something wrong or?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're both wrong. It should be$$\frac12\left(\ln(|t-1|-\ln|t+1|\right)+C.$$

Comment: Ah okay. Assuming $t-1 > 0$, can I simplify the expression to $ln\left(\sqrt{\frac{t-1}{t+1}}\right)$ ?

Comment: @fejz1234 Yes, you can.

Comment: Ok, but shouldnt the derivative of that simplification be equal to $\frac{1}{t^{2}-1}$? Seems not so straight forward to see..

Comment: @fejz1234 It may not be straightforward, but it is true nevertheless.